# How make a batch file that starts any program after restarting the system?

Tags: shell, batch-file, command

Hey There im a luking for some help to make a batch file that can start any program or exe after computer is restarted not before that

Comment: Umm, so make a batch file and put it in the Startup folder? What specifically are you having a problem accomplishing?

Comment: Dear Falcon, what i want is there is specific batch file which should run after restart

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to put it into the startup folder, located here: `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` but change `USERNAME` to your username. Everything in that folder will be executed when the computer starts. And so when you're done you can just remove the batch file from that folder. Or you could even make your batch file do that automatically.